# How to render multiple components in react which all take data entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to allow the user to press a button which renders new components, each of these components taking in data. This is the code I have so far:

```
class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: '', number: '', events: []};
  }

  onClick(){
  //to implement
  }

  numberOnChange(value) {
    this.setState({ number: value });
  }

  textOnChange(value) {
    this.setState({ text: value});
  }

  onClickNewEvent(value) {
    const temp = this.state.events;
    temp.push('');
    this.setState({events: temp})
  }

  onClickRemoveEvent(value) {
    const temp = this.state.events;
    temp.push('');
    this.setState({events: temp})
  }

  render() {
    let event=
      <div>
        <div>Input a number</div>
        <div> <InputNumber min={0} defaultValue={0} onChange={(value) => this.numberOnChange(value)} /> </div>
        <div>Input some text</div>
        <div><Input placeholder="Input text" onChange={(value) => this.textOnChange(value)}/></div>
      </div>;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Button onClick = {() => this.onClickNewEvent()}>Create new event</Button>
          <Button onClick = {() => this.onClickRemoveEvent()}>Remove an event</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button onClick = {() => this.onClick()}>Enter</Button>
        </div>
        {this.state.events.map((value, index)=>{
          return <div><Card key>{event}</Card></div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

With this example, obviously whichever event I make a change in, it will change the same parameters in the state. How can I change this so that the data for each event is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the required values inside the events list.
*(btw. you should not use `temp.push`, because you should never mutate the state directly)*
e.g.:

```
onClickNewEvent(){
    this.setState({
        events: [
            ...this.state.events, // copy events, to avoid mutating state directly
            { inputNumber: 0, inputText: 'xyz'}
        ]
    });
}
```

The `let event=` part is always the same, but you need different details for each event.
You should create an own component (e.g. `MyEventComponent`) instead of the `let event = ...` part, and then pass the values and the onChange function inside the loop,  e.g.:

```
{this.state.events.map((item, index)=>{
    return <MyEventComponent
        index = { index }
        number = { item.inputNumber }
        text = { item.inputText }
        textOnChange = { this.textOnChange( index, value ) }
    />;
})}
```

The local `textOnChange` has to be changed so that it used the index of the item:

```
textOnChange(index, value) {
    const newEvents = [ ...this.state.events ]; // copy events, to avoid mutating state directly
    newEvents[ index ].text = value;
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        events: newEvents
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you give more information on how to create `<MyEventComponent>`, do I need to do this in a seperate file? What would it look like?

Comment: I guess that would be off-topic under this question. I suggest to have a look at e.g. [tutorial about react-component-composition](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-composition/), [react components-and-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), [thinking-in-react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), or open another question about how to build react components.

Comment: I understand how to create a react component generally, I'm just unsure on how to pass the information between my original one and this new one.
For example, you could pass the inputNumber and inputText to the new react component through props, but then how would you change the state in the original component when a number is input

Comment: I managed to figure it out using this resource: https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I updated my answer to show how to change the state in the original component.